# WordPress : How can add post from frontend with feature images

Tags: php, wordpress

How Can we add feature image in custom post type from front end WordPress. Can anyone help for it ? I tried for it but does not get right result. Please help for it.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="postBlick">
        <input type="text" name="wpmp_title_1" placeholder="Title" />
        <?php wp_editor( '', 'wpmpeditor1', array('textarea_rows' => 10, 'textarea_name' => 'wpmp_editor_1') ); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="wpmp_buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </div>  
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="12awe5as14yu35" />
</form>
```

Comment: You want to use the media up loader in the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is now updated. You can use the below function.
`set_post_thumbnail( $post_id , $attach_id);`. Look at the below link.

[Look at this link of WordPress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134451/upload-featured-image-from-front-end-using-wordpress-add-media-button)

Comment: its not what i need ,,, i need only add feature image from front

Answer (score 0):

perhap you need to show code that process submitted form not only frontend form code. it will help others to give the best direction